# Robocopy, what's the total time to run the copy?

Tags: robocopy

Robocopy shows what seems to be the time it took to do the copy...but it shows two, which of the two is the right one?

[image: robocopy time used]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Robocopy shows what seems to be the time it took to do the copy...but it shows two

The time under the total column is the sum of:

> Copied Time - spent copying files (excluding retry wait times) 
> FAILED Time - spent waiting between retries for failed operations  
> Extra  Time - spent scanning directories and performing other functions

Source: [How to view the robocopy results correctly? - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-view-the-robocopy-results-correctly/abb4384f-ed1f-4b07-9661-d5d0466992a6)

```
total - copied = failed + extra
```

Comment: @harrymc Yes it does - `total - copied = failed + extra`

Comment: @harrymc Please - the question is about **times** not *bytes**. You should stop digging. `6:03:32 = 5:59:31 + 0:00:00 + 0:04:01`

Comment: @harrymc If you want to talk about bytes you haven't included `12.47m`

Comment: Thank you masters.